# Multiple sequence alignment with gaps

Tags: sequence-alignment

I'm working on a problem where the elements of multiple arrays need to be aligned with each other. While doing some research on algorithms that could possibly be applicable to this task, I stumbled on sequence alignment. I believe this is very similar to what I'm trying to achieve.

In short, I need to have equal elements aligned with each other across multiple arrays. However, the difference with my problem compared to sequence alignment seems to be that the latter doesn't tolerate gaps. On the other hand, gaps would be perfectly acceptable for me. So, for example, given input:

`[A, ,B,A, ]`

`[ ,C, ,D,A]`

`[B, ,C,B,A]`

A desired output would be:

`[A,B, , , ,A]`

`[ , ,C, ,D,A]`

`[ ,B,C,B, ,A]`

But there cannot be any errors. That is, every column must contain elements of the same value.

Would it be possible to achieve the desired result with sequence alignment algorithms?